# Tokenize not working with any string input

Tags: python, string, nltk, typeerror, tokenize

I previously posted about a string I extract from a link, for which I want to apply tokenize, with no luck. So tried a simplified example:
my command line is very simple:

```
a="Any Random text at all , nothing freaking works"
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(a)
```

I consistently get:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I have tried `str.(a)`, `a.split`, `a=a[0]`, and checked :

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

is there something wrong with my Python? I have checked examples and this apparently should be working. Would really appreciate it if someone could run and see if they get results and if so, what might be wrong with my Python

[image: Added image of error]

Comment: Just tried in Python 3.5.1 - no issue. Are you sure your code is exactly the same as you posted here?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes! I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: @ElnazSalehzadehNobari I seriously doubt this is your code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ do you get an error or does it run smoothly?

Comment: No error. On python 2 or 3. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Just tried in python 2.7.13 and got no error...

Comment: @coder I just added an image of my error, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the problem in nltk package itself. As in the picture, it is not the parameter passed in but literal `['']` in `nltk/data.py` which is considered to be list and converting to string.

Re-install nltk package may help?

show the 69th line of `nltk/data.py` it should be `path = []`

Comment: Thanks alot, I have been able to fix it not via re-installing, but by redefining all the paths and copying and pasting needed file paths manually as follows: nltk.data.path=['H:\\/nltk_data', 'C:\\nltk_data', 'D:\\nltk_data', 'E:\\nltk_data', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\nltk_data', 'C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\lib\\nltk_data','C:\\Program Files\\Python35\\taggers\\averaged_perception_tagger','C:\\Program Files\\Python35','C:/Program Files/Python35/tokenizers/punkt/PY3']                  I was hoping to avoid this by simply using  nltk.data.path="C:/Program Files/Python35" but doesnt work

Comment: On Windows, please see this https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9